# Find nginx version?

Tags: nginx, version, command-line-interface

I have installed nginx on Debian 7 with the following steps

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo service nginx start
```

I have confirmed that this starts nginx by accessing the hostip from the browser. How do I find out the version of nginx?

`nginx -v` fails with the '`command not found` error

I verified that nginx exists in the usr/sbin directory and that directory is added to the $PATH variable

Comment: I just tried what you described above (as a regular system user and as root)  on one of my systems: I got: `nginx -v` => 
`nginx version: nginx/1.8.0` - I guess, something with your PATH variable could be wrong aka misconfigured?

Comment: So `/usr/sbin/nginx -v` doesn't work either?

Comment: Tried /usr/sbin/nginx -v, same response

Comment: execute `whereis nginx` to find out where you nginx is located then use that path

Comment: "sudo apt-get install nginx" will install nginx. What is the need of "sudo service nginx start"?

Answer (score 84):

It seems that your nginx hasn't been installed correctly. Pay attention to the output of the installation commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

To check the nginx version, you can use this command:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/0.8.54

$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/0.8.54
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-0.8.54/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
```

For more information:
http://nginxlibrary.com/check-nginx-version/

You can use `-v` parameter to display the Nginx version only, or use the `-V` parameter to display the version, along with the compiler version and configuration parameters.

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I try to add **sudo**

```
sudo nginx -v
```

[image]

Comment: There's no point in blacking out text in an image if you're going to leave it readable.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't know where it is, locate nginx first.

```
ps -ef | grep nginx
```

Then you will see something like this:

```
root      4801     1  0 May23 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
root     12427 11747  0 03:53 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
nginx    24012  4801  0 02:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process                              
nginx    24013  4801  0 02:30 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

So now you already know where nginx is. You can use the -v or -V. Something like:

```
/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx -v
```

Answer (score 5):

My guess is it's not in your path.
in bash, try:
`echo $PATH`
and
`sudo which nginx`
And see if the folder containing nginx is also in your $PATH variable.
If not, either add the folder to your path environment variable, or create an alias (and put it in your .bashrc) ooor your could create a link i guess.
or `sudo nginx -v` if you just want that...

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have permissions to run the following commands.

If you check the man page of nginx from a terminal

`man nginx`

you can find this:

```
-V             Print the nginx version, compiler version, and configure script parameters.

-v             Print the nginx version.
```

Then type in terminal

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
```

If nginx is not installed in your system `man nginx` command can not find man page, so make sure you have installed nginx.

You can also find the version using this command:

Use one of the command to find the path of nginx

```
ps aux | grep nginx
ps -ef | grep nginx

root       883  0.0  0.3  44524  3388 ?        Ss   Dec07   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
```

Then run from terminal:

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -v

nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running command `whereis nginx`. It will give you the correct path of the nginx installation, in my case nginx is installed in `/usr/local/sbin`, so I need to check if this path exists in output of command `echo $PATH`. If you don't find the path in the output of this command, then you can add this.

Suppose the output of my `echo $PATH` command is this:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/nginx/sbin
```

Then I can append the path `/usr/local/sbin` in $PATH by following command:

```
~$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/nginx/sbin"' >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

Please check your nginx installation path may differ from mine, but the steps for adding them are same.

Answer (score 1):

search if iginx is installed or any package in your system

```
which nginx
```

OR

```
sudo which nginx
```

if previously nginx installed result will be like this
/sbin/nginx
/bin/nginx

if you use rhel, it will show you all installed modules

```
yum search nginx
```

OR
**check nginx version in rhel**

```
rpm -q nginx
```

Result look like this

> nginx-1.14.1-9.module+el8.0.0+4108+af250afe.x86_64

OR

```
sudo nginx -v
```

Result look like

> nginx version: nginx/1.14.1

don't use "nginx --version" it will show unexpected errors. I'm a RHEL user.

Comment: If my comment helps you please upvote.